# Music starts automatically when headphones are plugged into the iPhone

Tags: music, iphone

I have an iPhone 5 with the last version of iOS, 10.3.2. When I plug in the headphones into the jack, the music application starts automatically on the screen block, and starting to play music. I have no open application in the background when this happens.
What are the reason and can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most normal headphones don't do this but some might or might not start playing. Try pausing your music before you unplug. That should work as a temporary fix.